# Laptop bricked after uninstalling dual boot

Tags: bios, grub, dualboot

I have an Acer Swift 5 running windows 11. I wanted to install Manjaro for dual booting, so I created a new partition, changed SATA mode to AHCI and installed Manjaro to that partition. I later changed my mind when the desktop was glitching, so I deleted the partition from Windows, then extended the windows partition. Unfortunately I then made the mistake of restarting. Now my computer boots into grub rescue, with an unknown filesystem error. I can't find a way into the BIOS settings.

I saw tutorials on uninstalling dual boot that said to use a windows recovery disk, but I couldn't boot to one of those because I can't access BIOS settings.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: For BIOS (UEFI) try (from cold start) F2 repeatedly.  Make sure your dual boot stuff did not change UEFI to legacy and remove Secure Boot (death to Windows 11)

Comment: Ok, I got it working. What can I do from the BIOS to get back to windows boot manager?

Comment: I do not think you can fix the boot manager from BIOS (UEFI).  You may need to reinstall Windows   Be careful what you try to do with Windows 11

Comment: Is there anything I can do without an install disk? I don't have one, and it annoys me that windows still exists somewhere in the drive.

Comment: Contact Acer for a Recovery USB Key. They should ship you one.

Comment: That it *boots into grub rescue* means the boot order, as expected, still has the now non-existent Manjaro. As expected because simply deleting partitions NEVER changes this setting. In UEFI > Boot you should be able to change it back to Windows.

Comment: What you call "BIOS" is actually UEFI (and has been since at least a decade ago). Regardless of terminology the way to access it is the same as before, as explained before and you confirmed as working. So, again, find the Boot menu and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an Acer Swift 5 running windows 11
>
> I wanted to install Manjaro for dual booting, ... I later changed my
> mind

Windows 11 must maintain UEFI (and so GPT) and Secure Boot. Trying to go back to legacy will kill Windows 11.

For experimenting like this (where you may change your mind), and indeed, for many instances where multiple operating systems are required, run them in a virtual machine. This is a much better approach with Windows 11.

To get your laptop working correctly again, contact Acer Support and get a proper Recovery USB.   That will rebuild partitions including the Recovery partition.

A solid repair now and virtualization will keep your machine running much longer without having to repair or rebuild it.

Comment: I disagree with your assessment. It should always be possible to change the boot order back to "Windows". In UEFI system bootloaders co-exist, installing a Linux distro does not delete/replace the Windows bootloader.

Comment: It depends on the version of operating system whether it will dual boot in compliance with Windows 11.  The OP got into BIOS (UEFI) and was not able to fix the issue and hence my suggested answer.

Comment: Any major Linux distro is compliant. CPU and TPM requirements are immaterial and Secure Boot is supported. That the user wasn't able is irrelevant, unfortunately most people still don't understand the EFI boot process even after a decade or so. That's why I systematically suggest users here and elsewhere to learn the basics (and have proper backups) before messing with dual-boot. If the OP knew about the boot process, checking UEFI > Boot would be the go to troubleshooting immediately after deleting the Linux partition but there's zero mentions about a missing Windows bootloader.

Comment: My point was to not mess with dual boot just to see and experiment.  I did clarify that.

Comment: And I agree entirely with your advice. I do disagree with the need for a Windows repair as in it *may* need it for many other reasons but not for the reason expressed in the question which is only one more to add to the pile of "doesn't know how to manage a UEFI multi-boot". +1 for the effort.